# How can I search for an object in an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I created an object named `Tool` and appended some of them in an array in my iOS app. Now I want to search for some of them displayed in a table view. How can I search for a specific parameter in `Tool`?

```
class Tool {
    var name = String()
    var type = String()
    var status = String()
    var id = Int()

    init(name: String, type: String, status: String, id: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.status = status
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

Add the Items:

```
//Toolbox-Filler
var tools: [Tool] = []
var searchTools: [Tool] = []
```

Table View:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchTools.count
    }else {
        return tools.count
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifer, for: indexPath) as! ToolboxCell
    if searching {
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = searchTools[indexPath.row].name
        cell.typeLabel.text = searchTools[indexPath.row].type
        cell.statusLabel.text = searchTools[indexPath.row].status
    }else {
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = tools[indexPath.row].name
        cell.typeLabel.text = tools[indexPath.row].type
        cell.statusLabel.text = tools[indexPath.row].status
        }
    return cell
}
```

Search for items:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchTools.append(contentsOf: tools.filter { $0.name == searchText })
    searching = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = false
    searchBar.text = ""
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Is this the correct way? Xcode shows an error while testing.

Comment: Note your class properties can be declared as `let name: String` `let id: Int` etc (if you want to be able to change them later then they can be `var`). There's no use in redundantly initializing them as `String()` and `Int()` .

Answer (score 2):

You're a little off on your [filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) syntax. It should probably be this:

```
searchTools = tools.filter { $0.name == searchText }
```

This will give you all the `Tool`s with the `name` field equal to the current search text (a literal comparison).

Or, with, to account for [case sensitivity and other localization issues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412098-localizedcaseinsensitivecontains):

```
searchTools = tools.filter { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, there's no more error messages for my problem; but: the search function is not working...do you think the rest of my code ist correct as shown further up?

Comment: And: Is it possible to show all tools again if the user clears the search-bar?

Comment: What you’re showing is fine. But, there’s a lot of code you aren’t sharing. You have to make sure that when you’re searching, all of your table view methods return from searchTools and not tools.

Comment: Second question: yes. Don’t show or filter results if the search text is empty.

Comment: I've just updated the post with some more code; I found out, that I have to append the filtered items...ist that correct? // yeah, thanks, I will build a if-statement therefor

Comment: No, you should not be appending the `searchTools` array. The code I gave you (the first line), will only return an *exact* match. Try the second one instead. You also need to test for empty in your `textDidChange`